# Roll a pair of dice. What is the joint probability mass function of the low and high points rolled?

Tags: probability

> Roll a pair of dice. What is the joint probability mass function of
> the low and high points rolled?

### Attempt

Let $X$ be the high point rolled and $Y$ be the low point rolled. We want to compute $P(X=x, Y=y)$. The sample space is all pairs $(i,j)$ so that $i,j$ range from $1$ to $6$.

Here there is a confusion I have. $P(X=x,Y=y)$ if $x,y$ are fixed, then we know that if $x \neq y$, that probability can be true in only two cases: when $x>y$ or $y>x$. So, we have

$$ P(X=x, Y=y) = \frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{36} = \frac{2}{36} $$

but, if $x = y$, then $P(X=x, Y=y) = \frac{1}{36}$.

However, if $x,y$ are not fixed, then how isnt it $p(x,y) = \frac{30}{36}$? for the first case and $\frac{6}{36}$ for  the second case?

Updated:

Let $X$ be the high point rolled and $Y$ be the low point rolled. The sample space consists of all points $(i,j)$ so that $1 \leq i,j \leq 6$. We want to find $P (X=x, Y=y)$. Notice that when $x>y$, then we can have either $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$, two possible outcomes that give $x$ as the high and $y$ as the low, while if $x=y$, only $(x,x)$ satisfies the requirement. Therefore,

$$ P (X=x, Y=y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{2}{36}, & x > y \\[1em] \dfrac{1}{36}, & x=y \end{cases} $$

Comment: $P(X=x,Y=y)$ is $0$ if $x<y$, $1/36$ if $x=y$ and $1/18$ if $x>y$.

Comment: I dont understand. IM just seeing my notes and the solution reads: 

for $x<y$ the event outcomes are $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$ which gives 2/36 .

how come this 2 comes from ?

Comment: When $x<y$, there are two ways of getting $x$ and $y$ on your roll: the blue die could come up $x$ and the red die $y$, or the blue die could come up $y$ and the red die $x$.

Comment: got it now. thanks

Comment: see my updated solution. Does it look better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this figure of the state space help?

[image]

Comment: thanks for your hint. See my updated solution. Does it look better now?